# XText Disable Full Build

Tags: xtext

Generated file of my dsl is made of all resources in the project. I made that generator is loading all resources and file is made successfully.

Speed of that operation is fine though there are moments while it completely isnt.
When Full Build or Recovery is triggered, XtextBuilder iterates all resources and runs generator for each of them. In my dsl, this causes exactly same file to be generated 300 times(thats how many resources I have).

How do I disable those types of file generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve this differently. one option could be to register a custom `org.eclipse.xtext.builder.IXtextBuilderParticipant` and put your complete generation logic there. (alternatively have a look at the default impl `org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant`)

```
override bindIXtextBuilderParticipant() {
    MyBuilderParticipant
}
```

in your logic you would call the generator for the first delta only, not for all changed files

Comment: Could you give me tip of how to override IXTextBuilderParticipant? XTextBuilder has field RegistryBuilderParticipant but when I try to bind that class in RuntimeModule, I am getting Guide creation error

Comment: It works great, even if i paste multiple respositories it builds just once. Thanks for help, you have saved me a lot of time.